# Jackson deserialization using JsonParser distinguish between the direct object and objects within array

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am using the `Jackson` for the Deseilization of the JSON. The `Deseilization` works perfectly for a JSON with `CustomerDocument`. However, I have a new requirement in which I need to find whether provided JSON has `CustomerDocument` or just `Customer`.

I am able to develop the logic for both but the problem is that when I try to merge it won't work for `CustomerDocument`. I am looking for a solution that would work for both. All I would like to do is build the logic to differentiate the incoming JSON based on `customerDocument` and single `Customer`.

Following is the `CustomerDocument` JSON:

```
{
  "isA": "CustomerDocument",
  "customerList": [
    {
      "isA": "Customer",
      "name": "Batman",
      "age": "2008"
    }
  ]
}
```

Customer.class:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

JacksonMain:

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);
        
        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();
        
        //Go until the customerList has been reached
        while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("customerList")) {
            jsonParser.nextToken();
        }
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
            final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
            Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, Customer.class);
            System.out.println(event.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly and produces the following result:

```
Customer(isA=Customer, name=Batman, age=2008)
```

**Scenario-2**

Now user can provide the direct `customer` object without the `customerDocument`. Something like this:

```
{
  "isA": "Customer",
  "name": "Superman",
  "age": "2013"
}
```

'Customer.class' would remain the same and `JacksonMain` would be modified to:

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();


        final JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        final String inputType = jsonNode.get("isA").asText();

        if (inputType.equalsIgnoreCase("Customer")) {
            Object singleCustomer = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, Customer.class);
            System.out.println(singleCustomer.toString());
        } else if (inputType.equalsIgnoreCase("CustomerDocument")) {
            //Go until the customerList has been reached
            while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("customerList")) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
            }
            jsonParser.nextToken();

            //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
                final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
                Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, Customer.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a single `CUstomer` this would produce the following result:

```
Customer(isA=Customer, name=Superman, age=2013)
```

For the same code now if I provide the `CustomerDocument` (the first JSON) then it would not work and fail with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getText()" is null
    at stackover.JacksonMain.main(JacksonMain.java:32)
```

I know this issue is happening because of the line

```
final JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
```

Can someone please explain how to make the code work for both the type of JSON `customerDocument` and just single `Customer` using Jackson? I just want to differentiate whether incoming JSON is `customerDocument` or single `Customer`. Any help would be really appreciated.

1. I want to use Jackson to make the differentiation between both the input.
2. It would be great if there is no need to create any `additional classes`. However, it's fine if there is a need to create an `interface` to achieve this.
3. My `CustomerList` can be very huge so I am reading one by one so it does not make much memory. hence I do not have the `CustomerDocument` class with `List<Customer>` rather I am looking over it and mapping one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use Jackson sub type to de-serialize between `Customer` and `CustomerDocument`.

Something like following,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String s = "{\"isA\":\"CustomerDocument\",\"customerList\":[{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Batman\",\"age\":\"2008\"}]}";
//        String s = "{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Superman\",\"age\":\"2013\"}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        BaseResponse baseResponse = om.readValue(s, BaseResponse.class);

        if (baseResponse instanceof CustomerDocument) {
            CustomerDocument cd = (CustomerDocument) baseResponse;
            System.out.println("Inside If..");
            cd.getCustomerList().forEach(System.out::println);
        } else if (baseResponse instanceof Customer) {
            System.out.println("Inside Else If..");
            Customer cs = (Customer) baseResponse;
            System.out.println(cs);;
        }
    }
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Customer.class, name = "Customer"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CustomerDocument.class, name = "CustomerDocument")})
interface BaseResponse {}


@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class Customer implements BaseResponse{
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class CustomerDocument implements BaseResponse{
    private String isA;
    private List<Customer> customerList;
}
```

*PS - Uncomment the string in `main` method to illustrate the other case.*

#### Update

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String s = "{\"isA\":\"CustomerDocument\",\"customerList\":[{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Batman\",\"age\":\"2008\"},{\"isA\":\"Customer B\",\"name\":\"Superman\",\"age\":\"2013\"}]}";
//        String s = "{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Superman\",\"age\":\"2013\"}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = om.readTree(s);
        String type = node.get("isA").asText();

        if (type.equals("Customer")) {
            Customer c = om.readValue(s, Customer.class);
            System.out.println(c);
        } else if (type.equals("CustomerDocument")) {
            JsonNode nextNode = node.path("customerList");
            List<Customer> cl = om.convertValue(nextNode, new TypeReference<List<Customer>>() {});
            cl.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class Customer {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I understand how you are achieving the output. But is there any way to make it work without creating the `CustomerDocument` class? Because in my application I am using the standard classes which have been already created hence I am looping over the `CustomerList array` in JSON and assigning it to the `Customer` class. It would be great if there is a way to achieve the output without creating the additional classes. But I am ok with creating the interface. Thanks again. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Also, it woule be greate to use the `JsonParser` because my entier application is already built based on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I was able to get an idea based on your approach I was able to implement it a bit differently. But thanks for the explanation. I have posted the answer below.

Comment: Try JDDL library which is designed to do just such a thing. https://pretius.com/technologies/json-dynamic-deserialization-library/  https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.pretius/jddl

Comment: @Dariusz Thanks for the response but it does not help me as my whole application is already using the Jackson.

Comment: JDDL uses jakcson internally; in fact, if you do not configure anything, you get pure jackson deserialization, but with a different API. You can, however, implement a handler on the `isA` field that will customize the behavior for your objects.

Comment: @ray I used the approach mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/69028555/7584240 but when I am using this approach I am running into an issue, I have posted the question here if you get a chance can you please have a look and provide your response:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69043551/7584240

Comment: @Dariusz I am running into an issue while using the Jackson. If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide your response? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69043551/7584240

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me based on the above provided the answer:

BaseResponse interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Customer.class, name = "Customer")})
public interface BaseResponse {
}
```

Customer class:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements BaseResponse {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}
```

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        try {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, BaseResponse.class);
            System.out.println("SINGLE EVENT INPUT");
            System.out.println(baseResponse.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT");
            //Go until the customerList has been reached
            while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("customerList")) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
            }
            jsonParser.nextToken();

            //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
                final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
                Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, BaseResponse.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```