# Jackson @JsonTypeInfo is making the field unable to read during the deserialization of JSON

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am using Jackson to deserialize a JSON. The Jackson has to handle 2 things:

1. Identify if the provided JSON is a document and if so deserialize the elements in `CustomerList` one by one.
2. Identify if the provided JSON is a single `Customer` and if so then deserialize the `customer` directly.

I am able to achieve this and everything is working as expected but when I provide the `CustomerList` document then it's unable to read the `@Context` key-value pair.

Following is the `JSON` i am trying to deserialize:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    {
      "example": "https://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "isA": "CustomerDocument",
  "customerList": [
    {
      "isA": "Customer",
      "name": "Batman",
      "age": "2008"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is my Customer POJO class:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer implements BaseResponse {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Customer.class, name = "Customer")})
interface BaseResponse {
}
```

Following is the Main:

```
public class JacksonMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final InputStream jsonStream = JacksonMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.json");
        final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonStream);
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonParser.setCodec(objectMapper);

        //Goto the start of the document
        jsonParser.nextToken();

        try {
            BaseResponse baseResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, BaseResponse.class);
            System.out.println("SINGLE EVENT INPUT" + baseResponse.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT");
            //Go until the customerList has been reached
            while (!jsonParser.getText().equals("customerList")) {
                System.out.println("Current Token Name : " + jsonParser.getCurrentName());
                if (jsonParser.getCurrentName() != null && jsonParser.getCurrentName().equalsIgnoreCase("@context")) {
                    System.out.println("WITHIN CONTEXT");
                }
                jsonParser.nextToken();
            }
            jsonParser.nextToken();

            //Loop through each object within the customerList and deserilize them
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                final JsonNode customerNode = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
                final String eventType = customerNode.get("isA").asText();
                Object event = objectMapper.treeToValue(customerNode, BaseResponse.class);
                System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following response:

```
LIST OF CUSTOMER INPUT
Current Token Name : isA
Customer(isA=Customer, name=Batman, age=2008)
```

As we can see it's printing only `Current Token Name: isA` I would expect it to print `isA and @Context` because it's present before the `isA`.

Now if I remove the following code I have on the `interface BaseResponse`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "isA")
```

Then I am able to read the `@context` but that would result in following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `stackover.BaseResponse` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

I tried various things such as adding the following line:

```
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@context")
```

But nothing seems to work as expected for me. Can someone please suggest some work-around on how to make it work?

I tried to create a copy of the `Jackson JsonParser` but even that does not seem to work for me.

Please Note:

1. The `CustomerList` can have a lot of `Customers` hence I do not want to store the whole `CustomerList` into some `List` as it can take a lot of memories. Hence, I am using `JsonParser` so I can read one `JsonToken` at a time.
2. Also, I do not want to create a `CustomerList` class rather than that I want to read one Customer at a time and deserialize it.

Comment: I can see in your `@context` array one element is a string and other one is a object? Is it deliberate?

Comment: @ray Thanks a lot for the response. Yes, it's like that only. The JSON is actually coming from another application so I cannot modify it. I am running into an error when I am trying to differentiate between the `CustomerDocument` and `Customer`. Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you have only need `Customer` data. In my previous answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024894/16709163) (Not the updated one) I thought you want de-serialize into two different classes. That's why I have added `BaseResponse`, `Customer` and `CustomerDocument`. Since that's not the case you don't want it anymore.

I would suggest you to create a Jackson `JsonNode` from the `JSON` response you receive. So you can decide how to travers the tree. If you do that you **no longer need** `BaseResponse` or any of these Jackson related annotations.

Your `Customer` class,

```
class Customer {
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

You can use this approach to de-serialize.

Element `@context` cannot de-serialize directly. Because array not hold same type of elements within (one element a string other is an object).

```
String s = "{\"@context\":[\"https://stackoverflow.com\",{\"example\":\"https://example.com\"}],\"isA\":\"CustomerDocument\",\"customerList\":[{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Batman\",\"age\":\"2008\"}]}";
//        String s = "{\"isA\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"Superman\",\"age\":\"2013\"}";

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = om.readTree(s);
String type = tree.get("isA").asText();

if (type.equals("Customer")) {
    Customer c = om.readValue(s, Customer.class);
    System.out.println(c);
} else if (type.equals("CustomerDocument")) {
    JsonNode customerListNode = tree.path("customerList");
    JsonNode contextNode = tree.path("@context");
    List<Customer> cl = om.convertValue(customerListNode, new TypeReference<List<Customer>>() {});
    cl.forEach(System.out::println);

    if (contextNode instanceof ArrayNode) {
        ArrayNode contextNodeArray = (ArrayNode) contextNode;
        for (JsonNode node : contextNodeArray) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                System.out.println(node.asText());
            } else if (node instanceof ObjectNode) {
                System.out.println(node.path("example").asText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output,

```
Customer(isA=Customer, name=Batman, age=2008)
https://stackoverflow.com
https://example.com
```

#### Update

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = om.readTree(s);
String type = tree.get("isA").asText();

if (type.equals("Customer")) {
    Customer c = om.readValue(s, Customer.class);
    System.out.println(c);
} else if (type.equals("CustomerDocument")) {
    JsonNode customerListNode = tree.path("customerList");
//    List<Customer> cl = om.convertValue(customerListNode, new TypeReference<List<Customer>>() {});
//    cl.forEach(System.out::println);
    ArrayNode customerArrayNode = (ArrayNode) customerListNode;
    for (JsonNode node : customerArrayNode) {
        Customer customer = om.convertValue(node, Customer.class);
        System.out.println(customer);
    }

    JsonNode contextNode = tree.path("@context");
    if (contextNode instanceof ArrayNode) {
        ArrayNode contextNodeArray = (ArrayNode) contextNode;
        for (JsonNode node : contextNodeArray) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                System.out.println(node.asText());
            } else if (node instanceof ObjectNode) {
                System.out.println(node.path("example").asText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am able to follow up on what you are doing. The problem is that `CustomerList` can have a huge amount of customers so I do not want to load the whole thing into the memory. Hence, I am using the Jackson Streaming API so I can read the `CustomerList` but have only one customer at a time in memory. The approach suggested above loads the entier `CustomerList` elements into `List<Customer>` which I am trying to omit actually. That's also the reason I am running into the issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is there anything that I can try which will avoid loading of entier `CustomerList` and have only one `Customer` at a time. Also, work for identifying the JSON if its `CustomerDocument` or `Single Customer`? Looking forward to your response and suggestions. Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: You can loop through `customerList` Node as well

Comment: Yes that can be done but the problem is that the whole `CustomerList` has been loaded into the memory. I really want to avoid that. In the code mentioned in the question, I am not loading the whole `CustomerList` I am parsing over the JSON and trying to reach `Customer one-by-one`. This will ensure that only one customer is present in memory and provide better performance.

Comment: I think you miss understood my answer. Check my update. I meant something like this

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and for helping me out with the issue. Maybe I lack the understanding but going by the `updated answer route` don't we store the whole `CustomerList` in memory using `ArrayNode customerArrayNode`? After storing we are looping over it right so won't it impact the performance and memory? Because before I was using the `Jackson JsonParser` which was parsing one token at a time and then I was using the `jsonParser.readValueAsTree()` to read the whole `customer object` one at a time. So I was guranteed to have only one Customer at a time.

Comment: In the updated code first, we are storing the whole `CustomerList` in `ArrayNode customerArrayNode` so we will have the complete `CustomerList` in memory and then we are traversing over it to read one by one. I am no expert in Java or Jackson but won't it have a memory issue if 10000s customers are provided in the `CustomerList`? I am just trying to make my understanding better. Thanks in advance for your response and clarification.

Comment: True `JsonParser` uses less memory because it reads the JSON object as bunch of tokens and one by one. In your case I don't think you can use `JsonParser` because structure of your JSON object changes when `isA` parameter change. If the order has changed in your JSON object, you won't be able to de-serialize it correctly. For example you will iterate until you get `isA` parameter, when you get that parameter, you cannot go back to get `@context` data.

Comment: And what happened if you received `isA` as the last parameter in your JSON object.

Comment: As the JSON is coming from another application and it's a standard JSON for my application so there is no way for me to modify it. I can modify the code however I want but I want to make it as efficient as possible. Previously I did not have the single `Customer` requirement so it was easy for me to parse till `CustomerList` then read the each Customer using `jsonParser.readValueAsTree()`. Now, because of the single customer, I need to make the decision and due to this, I am losing the `@context`. Is there a way to store the `jsonParser` so if the first condition i.e single Customer fails

Comment: Then I can pass the copy of the `JsonParser` to the `catch` block so it has the `@context`. Something like that can be done? I tried but it was not working as expected maybe you can once guide me if it's possible to create a copy and use it rather than using the same `jsonParser` in both case

Comment: Well you can try to parse assuming everything is there. I'm not sure whether we can create a copy of `JsonParser` nr not. But you can create a new `JsonParser` for sure.

Comment: I tried various things and tried to create a copy of `JsonParser` still no luck for me. Nothing seems to work as I expected. The reason I am unable to read the `@context` is that `JsonParser` has been parsed halfway through so it loses it so when it comes to the `catch` block it has already passed the `@context` so I am unable to get it. Is there any other workaround that you can suggest to me? Because my client is saying we should not store the complete `CustomerList` in the memory as it can impact the performance due to huge size. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can mapped everything in `@context` to an array of simple POJO and then you can reuse that class when you have the `isA` value!

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am a bit unable to follow. Do you mean I can create another class `Context` which will have the `List<Object>`? But how do I handle it in both cases i.e when I have the `CustomerList` and single `Customer`? If possible can you please provide me a sample just to make my understanding better?